# Starting an apk on boot in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to start an Android application on boot? Perhaps by adding something to the init.rc script?

Answer (score 2):

If by "Android application", you mean something with a user interface, make it the home screen.

If by "Android application", you mean you have a small hunk of code you want to run around the time of boot, set up a `BroadcastListener` for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast.

You would only manipulate `init.rc` if you are doing things like creating custom firmware.

Comment: Basically I want to launch an actual android application, doesn't matter what. For example the browser. I thought adding something like am start -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity to a script then making that script into a service would work, but it doesn't. Is there any way to launch an app automatically on boot then?

Also, how do you make an app the home screen?

Comment: @Tony: "Is there any way to launch an app automatically on boot then?" -- make it a home screen. "how do you make an app the home screen?" -- add support for the `HOME` category to the `<intent-filter>` for the activity in the manifest. There is a sample home screen project in your copy of the Android SDK.

Comment: I am using the gem5 simulator, gem5.org. The way this simulator typically runs benchmarks, when using Linux anyhow, is by reading in a script then executing the script during boot. This way you can pass your script as a command line argument and can thus run any of your apps. This automates the process and makes it configurable. I want to be able to use this method to select which app to run on Android. Setting an app as the home screen defeats the purpose since I would have to have a separate disk image for each app I want to evaluate set as the home screen.

Comment: I guess what I am looking for is a way to replicate how the home screen gets called and instead call an app that I choose, as opposed to making the app the home screen.

Comment: @Tony: AFAIK that would require making custom firmware.

Comment: I found a way to do this. I made a service that calls a script that I made to launch the app. Then I started this service using: on property:sys.boot_completed=1. In my script I used sleep 10 to ensure that everything is setup then I use am start -n to launch my app. Seems to work for my needs.